# How to take visited Website log?

Tags: networking

I want to take logs for all the visited websites.

If any user entered a URL in browser address bar I want to take the log 
after I want to proceed to access the website and I want to block some websites for my users.

I'm using Linux machine. How to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a proxy server and force your users to route their web traffic through it. Since you want to run linux, I'd recommend taking a look at [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/). Also, you'll need to set your egress firewall rules such that web traffic is only allowed out of your network from the machine running Squid. That will force your users to use the proxy. Squid will be able to give you a log of all sites visited as well as blocking sites for all users or just for some of them.